# How to keep content over bg-image and keeping it vertically centered when we zoom in/out?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and i am facing a problem with the navigation section. I am making a navigation bar in which i need an image in the background and in front I want to add `div` containing `links` & `buttons` on that image.

Here is the HTML & CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", Courier, monospace;
}

.page-content {
  width: 120rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-section {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-link-container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 10.9%;
}

.nav-link-container ul {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 4.8rem;
}

.nav-link-container ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-btn-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4.8rem;
}

.header-section {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.header-section h4 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav-section">
    <img class="banner-img" src="https://lehndorff.com/music/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1600x230-banner.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="nav-link-container page-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Servers</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-links" href="#">Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nav-btn-container">
        <button class="nav-btn">Login</button>
        <button class="nav-btn">Sign up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <div class="header-section page-content">
      <h4>Hello World!!</h4>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I have two questions (watch the code snippet in full screen please):

1. When you will zoom in/out, you will see `header-section` stays in the middle without caring how much we zoom in/out while `nav-link-container` stays to the left side while zooming out/in. I think this is because of `position:absolute;`. So how do I fix it? Why is this happening?
2. I have set `margin:0;` & `padding:0;`in `*` but still if you see there is small pixel of gap between `header-section` and image. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

We have come up with a solution, Hope it will work for you.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/yk8ftdgn/

Here we have taken the image as a `background image`, instead of taking it in the `img` tag, and also made modifications in your CSS styles to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for replying but this isn't the result I wanted. I basically wanted that my `nav-link-container` stays on the bottom 1/3 height of the background image not contains the whole height of the background image. Can you help achieving that result.